# Mongodb instance alone vs mongodb on kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, cluster-computing, sharding

what is the better solution for running a mongodb instance? Lets say we have a running Kube cluster. MongoDb itself has its own clustering/sharding solution. We want this mongodb to grow in size and we expect it to get quite big, so we definitely need to use its sharding solution.

How does this fit into Kubernetes? Seems to me they don't really work well together? What I'm talking about is that Kubernetes "clones" pods over nodes, while the point of mongodb sharding is that you separate data over a cluster (not cloning data)? Am I wrong about something here?

Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

We have been running a sharded cluster of **Mongo** and **ES** in production with **TBs** of data for 3 years and never faced replication or other scaling issues.

i would suggest checking out this official link form MongoDb : https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster/

Using this you can deploy the shareded cluster of MongoDB on Kubernetes.

Basically mongo has its own **operator** which will operate and manage the PODs for you if any data replication required scaling etc.

It's required first to before you setup the cluster : https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/install-k8s-operator/

If you just want to use the helm chart check out this once : https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/bitnami/mongodb-sharded

If you want to setup eveything by own you can refer the : https://medium.com/google-cloud/sharded-mongodb-in-kubernetes-statefulsets-on-gke-ba08c7c0c0b0

One of my fav channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Lp6R4CmuKE

Comment: Just curiosity : what infrastructure stack you have been using ( storage/servers/os etc) since not everything is supported by k8s ?

Comment: GCP, GKE, COS, PD.